# How select text wrapped in quotation marks in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-8

For example, I have a string wrapped  in quotation marks, and I need select it all string wrapped. I usually select one by one each word using "Shift+Ctrl+Right Row" to the end. But it's not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the entire word by using the shortcut `Alt+Shift+PERIOD`.
if you are in a line with several words you can use this shortcut several times and the selection will move to the next words.

If by any chance you don't like the shortcut you can change it.

In Netbeans just go to menu Tools -> Options and choose Keymap. The shortcut that you will be looking is "Select Next Element".